# Drawing GL_POINTS

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing (I want to draw) a single point in the middle of the view and I have desired result on AVD (Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2 - API level 19, Intel Atom (x86), RAM 768, Use Host GPU), but I have issue while drawing it on real device [Nexus 5, Nexus 7 (2012 version)]. On real device there is only blank (clear color) view and no point in the middle.

Here's a complete code. It's relatively simple. Note I also tried push point data (position) by glVertexAttribPointer (glEnableVertexAttribArray).

Can you help me with this issue?

```
package com.example.point.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new PointView(this));
    }

    class PointView extends GLSurfaceView {

        public PointView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
            setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
            setRenderer(new PointRenderer());
        }

        class PointRenderer implements Renderer {

            private void checkError(String message) {
                int err = GLES20.glGetError();
                if (err != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(message + " -> " + err);
                }
            }

            private int createShader(int type, String source) {
                int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
                GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
                checkError("glShaderSource");
                GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
                checkError("glCompileShader");
                return shader;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
                int vertex = createShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "" +
                        "void main() {" +
                        "   gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);" +
                        "   gl_PointSize = 100;" +
                        "}");
                int fragment = createShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "" +
                        "precision mediump float;" +
                        "void main() {" +
                        "   gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 1, 1);" +
                        "}");
                program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
                checkError("glCreateProgram");
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertex);
                checkError("glAttachShader(vertex)");
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragment);
                checkError("glAttachShader(fragment)");
                GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
                checkError("glLinkProgram");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
                GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
                GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
            }

            private int program;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've read error and used float literal

```
"gl_PointSize = 100;" -> "gl_PointSize = 100.0;"
```

After this change I see desired result.